# Generating react native release aab

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to build a release aab from my React native project and after following all the procedures from the Reach native doc I’m still not able to do so.

I ejected my code ~expo eject~ and ran ~cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease~ but it keeps failing with this error

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ' :expo-updates:     compileReleasekotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more   details

* Try:
5 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
5 Run with
• Run with
-info or - debug option to get more log output.
-scan to get full insights.
2: Task failed with an exception.
* What went Wrong:
java. lang-StackOverflovError (no error  message)
Z
• Run with - stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

• Run with
-info or - debug option to get more log output.
> Run with - scan to get full insights.
© bash - android + Ow
# Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Execution optimizations have been disabled  for     2 invalid units) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
BUILD FAILED in 5m 21s
333 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 328 up-to-date
```

Comment: https://instamobile.io/android-development/generate-react-native-release-build-android/  seee here